# Keyboard shortcut "Alt+Shift+A" for chrome extension not registering on Win11 Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am not able to register the leyboard shortcut combination `Alt+Shift+A` for a chrome extension command in Google Chrome (Version 107.0.5304.122) in Windows 11. I mean that the command is not bound to the keyboard shortcut combination after installation, see screenshot taken from chrome://extensions/shortcuts.

[image]

There is no other chrome extension installed. I also checked all keyboard shortcut combinations defined by Google Chrome itself and was not able to find conflicting keyboard shortcut combos. Pressing the keyboard shortcut `Alt+Shift+A` has actually no effect at all. Choosing another keyboard shortcut combination is also working fine, e.g. with `Alt+Shift+G`. But, I would like to register the keyboard shortcut `Alt+Shift+A` to have it more intuitive for the users.

Interestingly, registering the command and keyboard shortcut `Alt+Shift+A` on a MacOS Google Chrome works without a problem, but not on a Win11 Google Chrome.

```json
"commands": {
  "accounts-open": {
    "description": "Open Accounts module",
    "suggested_key": {
      "default": "Alt+Shift+A",
      "mac": "Alt+Shift+A",
      "windows": "Alt+Shift+A"
    }
  },
}
```

Do you have an idea what I might be missing?

**UPDATED**

As described in [Win Google Chrome documentation](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179#zippy=%2Cgoogle-chrome-feature-shortcuts), the keyboard shortcut `Alt+Shift+a` is already bound, see shortcut. Hence, the keyboard shortcut combination defined by the chrome extension was not set when the extension was installed.

[image]

Comment: "I also checked all keyboard shortcut combinations defined by Google Chrome itself and was not able to find conflicting keyboard shortcut combos." --- [Chrome keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179) > Google Chrome feature shortcuts > Focus on inactive dialogues = Alt + Shift + a (but I have no idea what that means)

Comment: @ThomasMueller Thank you very much for spotting this. i totally missed this.